# Can't retrieve the full array from sqlite database in Android

Tags: android

I want to retrieve data from sqlite database and want to make array in android, but it only give me 9 elements there are many others, but it does not display. What can I do? suggest something...........

I have already tried:

```
String selectQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM rcategories";
Cursor c = db.sqliteDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);

if(c.getCount()>=1){
    recipeNamearray = new String[c.getCount()];

    int i=0;

    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        recipeNamearray[i]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("rcategary"));
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is edited code of your getdata:

```
    String selectQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM rcategories";
    Cursor c = db.sqliteDataBase.rawQuery(selectQuery1, null);

     if(c.getCount()>=1){
         recipeNamearray = new String[c.getCount()];
         int i=0;
         // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                recipeNamearray[i]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("rcategary"));        
                i++;
             } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
```

reference from: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/